# Limiting the number of pages non-members can visit

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

1. What is the best way to limit the number of pages a not-logged visitor can see? We should check if $_SESSION['id'] exists but how to limit the number of pages in a given period?
2. Search Engines consumes lots of traffic! Is it a pracical method to limit the time search engines spend on the website? e.g. allowing them to see only x pages per day or hour (as they are not logged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this on your framework:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['sc']))$_SESSION['sc']=0;
```

then, on your results page, add something like this:

```
$_SESSION['sc']++;
$c=$_SESSION['sc'];
if ($c>3) {echo "You have reached your search result limit."; exit;}
```

for your second question: Setting up a session variable to restrict search engines from crawling too much WILL fail. Robots don't have to store cookies from your site, even the session cookie, meaning that PHP won't be able to track the robot, if the robot doesn't want to be tracked.

I suppose that a way around this is to make sure that users are able to store cookies before they can crawl your search engine.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:
Use Sessions to keep that information. Also don't use an ID like the auto increment numbers which would be stored in your database, convert that into a very long string of no meaningful stuff, so the probability to someone changing the id and getting logged in into some other user's account would be very small...

For the second question I have no idea... Sorry...

Comment: How someone can fake session value? Session is server-side and is stored on the server, right? Anyway, I got your suggestion: using hash id.

Comment: Sessions are also stored in cookies on the user's computer. So when a page is requested the cookie is sent and is read by your page. Only the key/value pair is stored. All the other data is stored on your server... So if someone changes the value of the cookie to some other ID they can easily fake your system... SO that's why its better to use hashed ids...

Answer (score 1):

Answering 2:

If you don't care about SEO then you can block well-behaved Search Engines with [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html). Badly behaved Search Engines would be treated the same as badly behaved human users.

If you do care about SEO then you actively want them to visit your website! Sending them 4xx status codes or 503s isn't going to help get your content indexed.

However, Google Webmaster Tools offers the ability to ask for a [crawl rate](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/10/learn-more-about-googlebots-crawl-of.html).

Comment: I don't want to set the crawl rate manually in Webmaster Tools. I care about SEO, but Search engines keep visiting frequently, but there is not much updates to be re-indexed. For instance, in a blog with 1 entry every day, 100 old articles will be crawled by Google on the same day (which is useless for SEO). Moreover, it is not error page, but redirecting to login page.

Comment: @Ali: Search engines don't know your site. So they check if the page *still* exists. If you configure your webserver and the application properly, you can just give them a `304 Not Modified` answer which reduces the traffic heavily. Not to speak about serving your content with some guidance on when to revisit the page again.